# Сложить текущий элемент вектора с одним из предыдущих из этого же вектора

Tags: python, оптимизация, numpy, анализ-данных

Есть два вектора:

```
streak = np.array([3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3], int)
arr    = np.array([4, 5, 5, 6, 9, 1, 4, 5, 2, 3, 7, 8, 9, 8, 4, 3], float)
```

Числа в `streak` всегда больше нуля.

Задача cложить текущий элемент вектора `arr` с одним из предыдущих из этого же вектора. Индекс предыдущего взять из вектора `streak`.

В ответах приложил свое решение чтобы было понятнее. Решение рабочее, но не производительное т.к. в реальности векторы большие.

В результате должен получится вектор:

```py
[nan nan nan 11. 14.  6.  9.  9.  6.  5.  9. 10. 11. 17. 13. 12.]
```

Comment: Можете объяснить, каким образом у вас получается ваш вектор? По вашей задаче у меня получается [nan nan nan 11 14 7 ...], то есть несовпадение уже в шестом элементе. (А откуда берутся все числа в вашей программе я понять не могу).

Comment: @EzikBro мой вектор получается в результате исполнения кода, который я запостил в ответах.

Comment: Я это понимаю. Я не понимаю, каким образом "Задача cложить текущий элемент вектора arr с одним из предыдущих по индексу который взять из массива streak." решается вашим кодом и как она вообще связана с ним.

Comment: Понял, вы правы. Поправил описание. Если очень упрощенно, мне нужно получить вектор: arr[текущий] + arr[-streak].

Comment: Все еще ваша поставленная задача практически решается одной строкой `ans = [a[i] + a[streak[i]] for i in range(len(a))]`. Но данное решение дает отличный результат от приведенного вами, хотя они решают одну и ту же задачу с однозначным ответом. Это означает, что задачу сформулировали вы как-то некорректно.

Comment: "мне нужно получить вектор: arr[текущий] + arr[-streak]". Почему бы вам тогда так и не сделать?

Comment: Потому что индекс для arr из streak может зайти влево за пределы arr. Чтобы избежать этого я используд фукнцию shift.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
streak = [3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3]
arr    = [4, 5, 5, 6, 9, 1, 4, 5, 2, 3, 7, 8, 9, 8, 4, 3]

ans = [None] * len(arr)
for i in range(len(arr)):
    ind = i - streak[i]
    if ind >= 0:
        ans[i] = arr[i] + arr[ind]

print(*ans)
```

Для numpy-массивов переписать - дело пары минут. Я в вас верю

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np

streak = np.array([3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3], int)
arr    = np.array([4, 5, 5, 6, 9, 1, 4, 5, 2, 3, 7, 8, 9, 8, 4, 3], float)


def shift(arr, num):
    res = np.empty_like(arr)
    res[:num] = np.nan
    res[num:] = arr[:-num]

    return res


res = np.full_like(arr, np.nan)

for i in range(streak.size):
    arr_streak_shift = shift(arr, streak[i])

    print("{0} + {1}".format(arr_streak_shift[i], arr[i]))

    res[i] = arr_streak_shift[i] + arr[i]

print(res)
```

Comment: Это ответ на ваш вопрос? Если нет, то удалите его и дополните свой вопрос.

Comment: @strawdog да, это ответ на мой вопрос. Вопрос задал некоректно. Описание вопроса поправил.